# Installing Provisioning Profile on a new Mac

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

I got a new mac since the old one crashed and was trying to install my provisioning profile on new machine. Usually to do this I export the profile from organizer and import it on another machine. But since the old machine no longer works i can't do that .Simply downloading from the developer portal in apple.com/developer gives and error 'valid signing identity not found' which i guess is due to the missing private key. Do i need to revoke the certificate and create a new one ? What other option do I have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to revoke it since the private key cannot be regenerated, just revoke the old one and create the new one following the steps on apple developers website